# iis 7 error when trying to add defaultPath to httpError in web config

Tags: c#, iis, web-config

Hay when i add defaultPath="/Error.aspx" to my web config i get an error that tells me that i have an error to my config. The problem is that without that all is going well with out errors. I have below some relevant settings:

```
<httpErrors defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" >
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Err.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Err.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
```

Can you help me please. Do you know iis gives an error when i try to add a default path?

Comment: Can you provide us the error which it outputs?
If the error from IIS itself is too generic, look into the windows application event log.

Comment: Where are you putting defaultPath="/Error.aspx" notice the others have ~ in front of them.

Comment: @awright18 i put defaultPat in httpErrors and there is no ~ before

Comment: @Grumbler85 when i try to run the debugger from visual studio i've got this An error like this: Make sure the server is operating correctly. Verify if there are no syntax errors in web.config

Comment: @PopRadu What is the error if you open the page in an browser? What does the event log write?

Comment: Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/22709991/2164198 - no answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error only if I set setting "defaultPath" in file applicationHost.config of IIS.

Or you can set it with UI using next steps:
1) Open IIS
2) Select ServerName (not website)
3) Open menu "Error Pages"
4) Click "Edit Feature Setting" to the left.
5) Configure setting "Path" and other options in the popup.